# simple gui based gdb debugging over ssh

Tags: user-interface, vim, ssh, gdb, x11

I ssh into a linux VM which is setup remotely. I use Vim to write my code. For debugging however, I use netbeans through X11 which can sometimes be painfully slow. I tried using gdb buts its an efficiency killer. I love to hover over my variable and get to now their value rather that doing p variable_name , plus I like see and navigate through the code. Is there something light simple gui based debugging tool I can use. I have tried to use clewn http://clewn.sourceforge.net/ , but that doesnt work because it has a missing netbeans_intg feature. Is there any other similar vim gui based debugging tool ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question and as a `vim` user I understand your pain, but `emacs`' GUD mode is actually not bad and works well in the terminal (`emacs -nw`). http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrandUnifiedDebugger

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)
which is a gui for gdb, I think it's lighter than netbeans.

[cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/) is an interface to gdb but it is not a graphical one. It does not offer the possibility of hovering over a variable, but it shows you a window with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was in sort of your situation sometime ago, and you can have a look at my question about [using gdb with remote sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188964/using-gdb-with-remote-sources).
First of all, your problem with netbeans_intg feature is related to vim which has been compiled with no support for it. If you can rebuild vim yourself, you can then enable it.
 Otherwise, as you can see in the answer that I gave myself to my question, you can leverage clewn's remote-vim capabilities.
In a nutshell, you can have a "local" vim (i.e. on a desktop/laptop machine presumably), which must still be built with netbeans_intg support, but now it is a vim under your complete control (i.e. it's on "your" machine), while clewn will run on the linux host where gdb and your debuggee will run.
You can then keep the source files on your desktop/laptop and have the remote clewn sort of "drive" your local vim to the proper source files while debugging.
IOW: clewn will get information out of gdb to know exactly which file/line you're into and connect to remote vim and tell it: "hey, go grab this file and show it around this line", highlighting current line, breakpoints etc.
This is a great solution for when you have far-away deployed systems and you need to debug them with minimum impact on the host where they are running, and presumably no option to transfer there all of your source files.
I don't know if this fits in any way with what you're trying to do, but it did really change things for me.

Hth, 
Andrea.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GDB server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdbserver). Theoretcially, you should be able to start gdb on your linux machine in server mode and connect via GUI of your choice.  As long as that GUI supports remote gdb connections, which Netbeans does.